# Ansible when statement with variable from another task

Tags: ansible, .when

can someone help me please?
I want to create a folder at host "cfme_tester-0". 
For this I check variable "osp_version" from "undercloud-0" host and based on the result I should create a folder at the "cfme_tester-0" host.

Here is my playbook:

```
- name: take openstack version
  hosts: undercloud-0
  become: true
  become_user: stack
  tasks:
    - name: creating flavor
      shell: |
        source /home/stack/stackrc
        cat /etc/rhosp-release | egrep -o '[0-9]+' | head -1
      register: osp_version
      ignore_errors: True
    - debug: msg="{{ osp_version.stdout }}"


- name: set up CFME tester
  hosts: cfme_tester-0
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  tasks:
    - name: Run prepare script for OSP10
      debug:
        shell: |
          cd /tmp/cfme/ && mkdir osp10
      when: "'10' in osp_version.stdout"

    - name: Run prepare script for OSP13
      debug:
        shell: |
          cd /tmp/cfme/ && mkdir osp13
      when: "'13' in osp_version.stdout"
```

But an error occurs:

```
TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [undercloud-0] => {
    "msg": "10"
}

PLAY [set up CFME tester] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [cfme_tester-0]

TASK [Run prepare script for OSP10] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [cfme_tester-0]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check ''10' in osp_version.stdout' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional ('10' in osp_version.stdout): 'osp_version' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/root/infrared/rhos-qe-core-installer/playbooks/my_setup.yaml': line 20, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  tasks:\n    - name: Run prepare script for OSP10\n      ^ here\n"}
    to retry, use: --limit @/root/infrared/rhos-qe-core-installer/playbooks/my_setup.retry

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
cfme_tester-0              : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1   
undercloud-0               : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables are per-host (because otherwise, what happens when you run a task on multiple hosts and `register` a variable?).  In your first task, you are setting the `osp_version` variable for host `undercloud-0`.

If you want to use this variable in your second play, which is running on `cfme_tester-0`, then you should read the [Magic Variables, and How To Access Information About Other Hosts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts) section of the Ansible documentation.  You'll need to refer to the variable via the `hostvars` dictionary, so your second play will look like:

```
- name: set up CFME tester
  hosts: cfme_tester-0
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  tasks:
    - name: Run prepare script for OSP10
      shell: |
        cd /tmp/cfme/ && mkdir osp10
      when: "'10' in hostvars['undercloud-0'].osp_version.stdout"

    - name: Run prepare script for OSP13
      shell: |
        cd /tmp/cfme/ && mkdir osp13
      when: "'13' in hostvars['undercloud-0'].osp_version.stdout"
```

...but note that if you're just creating a directory, you would be better off just using the `file` module instead:

```
    - name: Run prepare script for OSP10
      file:
        path: /tmp/cfme/osp10
        state: directory
      when: "'10' in hostvars['undercloud-0'].osp_version.stdout"
```

Comment: Glad to help! If you are happy with this answer, you should mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark above and to the left.

Comment: I'm ok with variables now but another issue come. So I need to investigate more.

fatal: [cfme_tester-0]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "'shell' is not a valid option in debug"}

Comment: Well, it's telling you the truth.  `shell` isn't a valid option for `debug`.  `debug` only accepts `var` and `msg`; see the docs: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/debug_module.html. I think you just wanted a `shell` task there (see the update to my answer).

Comment: larsks, you are the best. You did my evening. Thanks a lot again!